# How do I get my players to clean up their mess after the game?

Tags: group-dynamics, social

For some background: I run a game of *Mage The Ascension* at the moment and when our groups gather we tend to get tea and snacks, but later on everyone just bails on me dumping the job of cleaning after them to me.  How can I make them clean their mess?

I am currently thinking of either rewarding experience to the one that cleans the table or take experience from those who bail on cleaning but I know that in-game solutions for out of character problems rarely work so I wanted to ask over here.

Comment: While I empathize with your frustration, I am not sure if this is an RPG-centric topic.  That said, we have a lot of Q&A dealing with social at table/away from table issues, so perhaps it's a good fit, although it may be a better fit [at a discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)

Comment: Have you *asked*?

Comment: I agree, this may be better for the "interpersonal skills" stack exchange.

Comment: This may be a better fit at the [Interpersonal Skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Just ask.

Have you tried simply asking them to clean up before they leave? It doesn't have to be aggressive or complex, just a simple request should do the trick.

> "Hey guys, I don't mind hosting the game at my place, but I would appreciate it if everyone could clean up their mess before leaving. It would only take a couple minutes if everyone tackles their own trash, and saves me a lot of trouble after the game."

I can't fathom them saying "no" just because of how plain rude that would be.